# How do I read values from photocells connected to analog pins of Arduino Uno?

Tags: input-devices

Generally, I need to connect my Arduino Uno to Mathematica and read 3 analog values from A0, A1, A2 in real-time.

As I understand, I have 2 ways of connecting Arduino to Mathematica:

**First:** I have a properly working Arduino IDE sketch that can be uploaded to the device from Mathematica (without using Arduino IDE) somehow like they do on this page - http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/936358

My particular working Arduiono IDE sketch is:

```
    int raw1 = 0, raw2 = 0, raw3 = 0;
    int x = 0, y1 = 0, y2 = 0, y3 = 0;

    void setup() 
    {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode( A0, INPUT );
    pinMode( A1, INPUT );
    pinMode( A2, INPUT );
    analogReference(INTERNAL);
    }

    void loop() 
    {
    while (x<=6000)
    { 
    raw1 = analogRead( A0 );
    y1=raw1;
    raw2 = analogRead( A1 );
    y2=raw2;
    raw3 = analogRead( A2 );
    y3=raw3;
    x++;               
    Serial.print( y1 );
    Serial.print("\t"); 
    Serial.print( y2 );
    Serial.print("\t");                
    Serial.print( y3 );
    Serial.println();
    delay(400);
    }
    }
```

**Second:** There are some commands in Wolfram Language that allow to communicate with my Arduino Uno without using Arduino IDE language. As I understand, my code in Wolfram language should be something like this (this program is supposed to read 3 values every 0.01 second for 1 second):

```
    Uno = DeviceOpen["Arduino", "COM3"];

    DeviceConfigure[Uno, <|"A0" -> "AnalogInput", "A1" -> "AnalogInput", "A2" -> "AnalogInput"|>];

    DeviceReadTimeSeries[Uno, {1, 0.01}, {"A0", "ReadMode" -> "Analog"}]
    DeviceReadTimeSeries[Uno, {1, 0.01}, {"A1", "ReadMode" -> "Analog"}]
    DeviceReadTimeSeries[Uno, {1, 0.01}, {"A2", "ReadMode" -> "Analog"}]

    DeviceClose[Uno]
```

Nevertheless, Mathematica doesn't compile this and gives such an error report:

```
    CCompilerDriver`CreateObjectFile::cmperr: Compile error: avr-g++: error:C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\arduinocompile1420c72c8f614b19b9df9d5891fcf275\SketchTemplate.cpp.c: No such file or directory
```

What is the problem?
Many thanks for any hint!

P.S. I use Mathematica 11.

P.P.S. Have attached the code we're discussing in the comments
[image: Here it is]

Comment: The file name `SketchTemplate.cpp.c` (cpp and c extenstion) looks a bit suspicious.

Answer (score 6):

I think the second approach should work. If it's not working for you, try the following with the first approach.

First, you need to fix the sketch by specifying the type of the variables y1, y2, and y3.

After uploading your sketch, open a connection to the Arduino.

```
dev = DeviceOpen["Serial", "COM3"]
```

Create a function to parse the incoming data.

```
parseData[{val1__, 9, val2__, 9, val3__}] := 
   ToExpression@FromCharacterCode@# & /@ {{val1}, {val2}, {val3}}
parseData[___] := Sequence[]
```

And set up a task to read the data.

```
rawReadings = {};
task = SessionSubmit@
   ScheduledTask[AppendTo[rawReadings, DeviceReadBuffer[dev, "ReadTerminator" -> 10]], 0.2]
```

Now you should be able to plot the values.

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[parseData /@ rawReadings], PlotLegends -> Automatic]// Dynamic
```

When you are done, remove the task and close the connection.

```
TaskRemove[task];
DeviceClose[dev]
```

*My results:*

On a Arduino Uno, I connected A0 to GND, and A1 and A2 to two potentiometers.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for Your feedback! But my Mathematica 11 doesn't recognize `SessionSubmit` and `TaskRemove`. Basically, this is what I get as an output: `ListLinePlot::lpn: Transpose[{}] is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers.` And `parseData /@ rawReadings` gives back nothing when evaluated in place.

Comment: Could you remove `SessionSubmit` and try `RunScheduledTask` instead of `ScheduledTask`.  And in the end you will need to use `RemoveScheduledTask` instead of `TaskRemove`.

Comment: Yes, that partly works out, but nevertheless, the error `ListLinePlot::lpn: Transpose[{}] is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers` doesn't go away, so it should be  something wrong with the function - it returns an empty list.

Comment: Also, should I upload the sketch from Arduino IDE and then close it or forget about Arduino IDE at all? Is there an algorithm which can tell one what to do in what order?

Comment: 1. (Set M aside) Are you able to read the three sensor values delimited by tabs and ending with the return character using Arduino's serial monitor? If not, there's some issue with your hardware. 
2. If the data is coming through Arduino's serial monitor, close the monitor. In M, evaluate  `dev = DeviceOpen["Serial", "COM3"]` followed by `DeviceReadBuffer[dev]` a couple of times,  and tell me what you are receiving. Finally evaluate `DeviceClose[dev]`.

Comment: **1)** Yes, I am. Using only Arduino IDE and the sketch which was given in the question description everything works perfectly. **2)** I receive a list of numbers which are though not similar to those I have in my serial monitor.

Comment: If you can share a small sample of the list of numbers you are receiving using `DeviceReadBuffer`, it will help me identify the issue.

Comment: **51, 52, 53, 9, 51, 51, 51, 9, 49, 57, 56, 13, 10, 51, 52, 55, 9, 51, \
51, 51, 9, 49, 56, 50, 13, 10, 51, 52** - This is the half of the list I got for the 3rd time actually. First 2 were 2-3 times bigger and contained many zeros in their first parts.

Comment: The data that you received the 3rd time seems fine. After you open the connection with `DeviceOpen` make sure that the Arduino is actually transmitting data by checking if the TX LED is blinking. Then start the scheduled task.  Also try to set the task as `task=RunScheduledTask[If[DeviceExecute[dev,"SerialReadyQ"],
AppendTo[rawReadings,DeviceReadBuffer[dev,"ReadTerminator"->10]];DeviceExecute[dev,"ReadFlush"]],0.4]`.

Comment: The TX LED is blinking, so I guess the data stream should be ok. I've tried the following code (without using Arduino IDE), which I have attached to the question description in P.P.S. and unfortunately it gives out the same error as I have described earlier :(

Comment: I saw your update. You should not be evaluating the whole thing in one cell!! Can you split it up as I have done in my answer! And also for good measure do `dev = DeviceOpen["Serial", {"COM3","BaudRate"->9600}]`

Comment: I've added what I get when I run my code divided in different cells.

Comment: The same result i get when I use `task = RunScheduledTask[
  AppendTo[rawReadings, 
   DeviceReadBuffer[dev, "ReadTerminator" -> 10]], 0.2]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69468/discussion-between-aleksandr-berezutskii-and-suba-thomas).

Comment: How can I add a time scale  to the plotted data?

Comment: @suba Thomas. What does 9 does on the line. parseData[{val1__, 9, val2__, 9, val3__}] := 
   ToExpression@FromCharacterCode@# & /@ {{val1}, {val2}, {val3}}
parseData[___] := Sequence[]

Comment: @JoseECalderon, ToCharacterCode["\t"] is where the 9 comes from. That is because the OP used \t to separate his values.

Comment: @Suba Thomas  Thanks! , this trouble me since I did not realized how Serial Character Code works.  From the stand point of speed, sending and receiving the data in HEX or binary format is an advantage?

Answer (score 0):

I am retaking the original subject of your question around why is **option number 1** not compiling.

From inspection at your error messages

*CCompilerDriver`CreateObjectFile::cmperr: Compile error: avr-g++: error:C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\arduinocompile1420c72c8f614b19b9df9d5891fcf275\SketchTemplate.cpp.c: No such file or directory*

shows an indication that you do not have a current C++ compiler with the necessary libraries. I am assuming you are using a Windows OS because your COM3 port is formatted for Windows O.S.   You also mentioned that your Mathematica 11 doesn't recognize `SessionSubmit` and `TaskRemove`

Your compiler error is looking for a avr g++ compiler. In the end days of v10 and early days of v11, Mathematica was limited to C compilers provided by Visual Studio 12 or earlier. I am suspecting that you have not installed a recent Visual Studio into your computer. This will rendered many of the functions based on Universal Windows Platform stranded.

It is a good idea to install a recent version of Visual Studio and include all the SDK libraries. There is a post on this subject that will help you on this.
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172717/11974 . Is is possible that you may have to reinstall WM afterward to endure that all variable *system path* are properly recorded

Also , will  like to comment on **option 2**.  Must people do not realized that the WM Arduino functions as shown in your application `Uno = DeviceOpen["Arduino", "COM3"];`throws away your loaded sketch. Mathematica will load its own version of a *Firmata* based protocol which controls communication with the device. Therefore, even though you uploaded option 1 sketch, when engaging the DeviceOpen["Arduino"....  override your sketch.

I have to acknowledge that the answer from @Suba Thomas is the best way to go and deserves full upvote.  His code offers a path for full control of the device. Even more,   will work on any pin from any of the other Arduino Boards and not limited to an Arduino Uno.