# Can I use Microsoft Visual Studio C compiler with V.11.3?

Tags: compile, version-11.3

Mathematica 11.2 supports the C compiler of Microsoft's Visual Studio, which is what I have. But Mathematica 11.3 does not. The only compilers that 11.3 seems to support are gcc and Intel, both of which are unavailable on my computer. Is the any way I can tell Mathematica to use the compiler that I have?
So in the reference it goes like this[image]
But if I try the code myself, it shows this, missing out most of the C compiler supported on windows.[image]Moreover, `CCompiler[]` does not show the visual studio compiler that I've already installed, showing `{}`, as if there is no C compiler installed.

Comment: If you experience a problem, please provide precise steps to reproduce it. Also, what is "SO"?

Comment: Are you running te Mac or WIndows platform?

Comment: Is your question "How to use Visual Studio compiler in MMA 11.3" ?

Comment: windows. I type Need["CCompiler"], and then get the types of compilers supported, but there's no visual studio

Comment: Add the code and the result Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CCompilers[]

Comment: Does your windows username contain bad characters?

Comment: @Coolwater no, just english characters.

Comment: @Szabolcs I've edited this question, please reopen it

Comment: There are multiple mistakes in the example you showed. Can you show a minimal example that uses the commands correctly and demonstrates the problem?  You have to use ``Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]`` and not `Needs["CCompilerDriver"]`.  You should run all this after restarting the kernel (note the red colouring on `CCompilers` indicating s context conflict).  You should use `CCompilers[]` not `CCompiler[]`.

Comment: Also, does it work correctly in M11.2 *on the same computer*?  (Show an example if you can.)  What is your OS version and *language*?

Comment: @Szabolcs Fixed the error, and the problem persist. It does run , but then I don't have the package of mathematica11.2 anymore. OS Windows 10, language Chinese simplified

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you have installed?  Did you install the C compiler (command line tools)?  Personally I use this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159 (I don't need the VS GUI, and the VS GUI can be installed *without* the C compiler).  I believe that with M11.3, the 2017 build tools also work.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes , that was exactly what i installed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ensure that you have the Windows 10 SDK and Universal Windows Platforms tools for C++

[image]

Also the Desktop Development Tools

[image]

[image]

Do a rebuild of VIsual Studio. Goo to Visual Studio 2017 Installer then under Visual Studio Community choose the MORE drop down bottom.

[image]

DO the same in Visual Studio Build.

[image]

After all these, Turn off computer and restart. Make sure that your code starts code with

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
CCompilers[]
```